# Does deleting branch from server delete history of that branch forever?

Tags: git

I created a branch 'test' (just for learning purpose) & pushed it to origin server. For branch 'test' I have two commits & I pushed them to origin. But I don't want those commits hence also that branch. Hence now, I'll delete branch 'test' from origin (and also locally by 'git branch -d test'):

```
git push origin :test
```

Will this delete everything about that branch (including those both commits) forever?

Also, can I create a branch with same name i.e. 'test'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No, deleting branches does not delete commits

A branch is just a pointer to a commit - if you delete the branch, the commits still exist and can be accessed directly by the commit hash.

Over time, git automatically deletes un-referenced commits/objects (garbage collection) but this isn't immediate. Github has a [helpful page on the topic](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) if you want more information on how to permanently delete pushed changes but *you don't need to do this* unless you specifically want to obliterate the contents of your unwanted and now orphaned commits.

### Yes you can create a new branch with an old name

If you've deleted a branch and want to recreate it with a different name - yes you can.

If the remote branch still exists and you want to publish to it, you'll need to force push (`git push -f`) the first time you push to the remote as the remote branch will probably not have a common history with your "new" branch with the same name.

Comment: Ok, when I will create a branch with an old name, will it use deleted branch's data (will it point older deleted branch)?. Because I created branch 'test' locally, then deleted it & again created branch wit same name 'test' & deleted it again. But when I deleted 'test' branch both times, I saw "Deleted branch test (was 86953b1)." Both times, I saw number '86953b1'. What is that? And why both times of deletion it was same?

Comment: `when I will create a branch with an old name, will it use deleted branch's data` No - unless you're creating the branch at exactly the same commit. If you delete a branch as far as git is concerned it never existed (`.git/config` information excepted). Use the [log](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) if you want to see what a branch contains (or any of the multitude of git guis).